# Focus textBox element from parent view

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to focus text box search element when pressing ctrl+f, but this text box located in contentControl of mainWindow. So when focus inside ContentControl i can focus it from handler of child view. But when focus in main window i should somehow to focus it from parent window. How can i do that?

```
MainWindow

<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mainWindowViewModel:SummaryViewModel}">
                        <mainWindow:SummaryView />
                    </DataTemplate>
 </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
 <ContentControl x:Name="InnerControl" Content="{Binding Path=ContentViewModel}" />

Child view:

<UserControl x:Class="View.Settings.MainSettingsView"

             Name="MainSettings"
             PreviewKeyDown="MainSettingsView_OnPreviewKeyDown">

                <TextBox Name="SearchBox"
                         Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTopNavigationStyle}"
                         TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" />

             </UserControl>
```

Comment: This sounds like a good candidate for the messenger pattern. Are you using any MVVM frameworks like MVVM Light or Prism?

Comment: No, just mvvm pattern

Comment: @olitee I think about messages but it looks like little overhead.

Comment: That's ok. The static key binding approach in the answer slow will probably meet your needs then. I tend to use the messenger approach for dynamic or assignable key bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach, working just within the UserControl, and not strictly MVVM, might be to create a `KeyTrigger` bound to the parent Window (that will capture the key events regardless of focus). You can achieve that with a `RelativeSource FindAncestor` binding. This searches up through the visual tree until it encounters the control of the type you've specified. In this case, we're looking for the main Window control.

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="View.Settings.MainSettingsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    Name="MainSettings">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:KeyTrigger Key="F" Modifiers="Ctrl" SourceObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MainSettings, Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="SetTextboxFocus"/>
        </ei:KeyTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <TextBox Name="SearchBox"
    Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTopNavigationStyle}"
    TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" />

</UserControl>
```

That `KeyTrigger` causes the `CallMethodAction` to call the `SetTextboxFocus()` method on the usercontrol. So all you need do is simply add this method to your usercontrol's code behind:

```
public void SetTextboxFocus()
{
    SearchBox.Focus();
}
```

Hopefully binding the KeyTrigger to the parent window, rather than the usercontrol, should fix your problem.

NOTE: I originally attempted to use the `CallMethodAction` to directly call the `Focus()` method of the SearchBox ... but this approach didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, it works and more elegant that my custom visual tree searcher)

Comment: No worries. Even with MVVM, it's best to look for the simplest solution first. The nice thing about this approach is that it keeps all the key-press behaviour within the usercontrol that responds to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use InputBindings for your case.

Add the below code in your mainwindow.xaml.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
              Gesture="CTRL+F" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Show the child usercontrol in keybindings command event.

For more [refer MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx)

EDIT 1:

Here I have added an example to show the textbox on pressing CTRL + F and hides on  pressing CTRL + F again.

**Prerequistes:**

As you have mentioned, you are not using Galasoft and just MVVM pattern. So, if you dont have RelayCommand.cs, Add it to your project.

*RelayCommand.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SO // Note: Change namespace
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:PopUpFind ="clr-namespace:SO"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ShowFindControl}"
              Gesture="CTRL+F" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <PopUpFind:PopUpUC Visibility="{Binding PopUpFindVisibility}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace SO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainModel();
        }   

    }
}
```

**MainModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SO
{
    class MainModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand ShowFindControl
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private Visibility _PopUpFindVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        public Visibility PopUpFindVisibility
        {
            get { return _PopUpFindVisibility; }
            set
            {
                _PopUpFindVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PopUpFindVisibility");
            }
        }
        public MainModel()
        {
            ShowFindControl = new RelayCommand(MakeVisible);
        }

        private void MakeVisible(Object obj)
        {
            PopUpFindVisibility = (PopUpFindVisibility == Visibility.Hidden) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how it helps to focus textbox in content control. It is just a binding

Comment: @Suhan Wait.. I will update my answer with an full working example.

Comment: @Suhan Updated answer... Check it.

Comment: The main difficultti is that we need to focus text box inside contentControl. In other word content of contentControl is view, inside this view located textbox that we need to focus. Your code doesnt solve this problem